# Retry logic on model save - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

User_code is generated and must be unique. What would be the easiest/cleanest way to do retry logic on this model save? I would like to verify the generated code first, and then if it's not found on the users table, create the user, if found, loop to retry. What would be the syntax for that? Thanks

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'user_name' => 'My user name',
        'user_code' => bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))
    ]);

    $user->save();

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you check the database when generating the code? That way, you only try to create once you got it right and the end user doesn't have to face an error that is not up to him/her.

```
do {
    $code = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    $record = User::where('user_code', $code)->get();
} while(!empty($record));

$user = User::create([
    'user_name' => 'My user name',
    'user_code' => $code
]);

return $user;
```

Comment: `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))` can this function generate same number twice? if not how you can get the same number for condition use `User::where('user_code', $code)->get()` its every time generate different number than you insert into db `'user_code' => bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))`  @marco-aurélio-deleu

Comment: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16) generates a random string, not necessarily unique

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the retry:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge(['user_code' => bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))]);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_name' => 'required|unique:users',
        'user_code' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);

    $user = new User;

    $user->user_name = $request->user_name;
    $user->user_code = $request->user_code;

    $user->save();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks That's clean. What would happen if the user_code is not unique when it saves?

Comment: If it is not unique, Laravel will redirect back and show the proper validation error, `save()` won't be triggered.

Comment: Ok, but this is all hidden for the end user, that's the reason why I want to try regenerating a new user_code and try to save again. I don't want to show the error to the user

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My mistake not presuming it at first. Deleu's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a unique string from the beginning. Still go for validation, of course.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user_code = bcrypt($request->user_name . openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    $request->merge(['user_code' => $user_code]);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_name' => 'required|unique:users',
        'user_code' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);

    $user = User::create($request);

    return $user;
}
```

A save() is implied by create().

Comment: Thanks, but user_name is not unique. The only unique column I have is id, but it wasn't created yet.

Comment: @user3489502 user_name should definately be unique. In any case you can use other things like time() to add entropy.